# SS_WHITERECT static using a dialog editor

Tags: visual-studio, winapi

How to create a design time filled SS_WHITERECT static equivalent using a dialog editor in Visual Studio? Maybe I am missing some property field that needs to be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the dialog editor, it's labelled **Picture Control**, and you need to set the **Color** property to *White*.

[image]

Comment: I see. That creates a rectangle with a border. Any way to create an all white filled rectangle? I have updated my question.

Comment: I don't think so. The picture control can display a bitmap so you could create a white bitmap and set the control to show it. Or sub-class and draw it yourself. Or just handle `WM_PAINT` in your dialog and draw it directly (not everything **has** to be a control).